# curl page source from text file containing URLs

Tags: curl, cat, xargs, url

I have a text file containing up to 100 URLs. I am able to curl the page source from them using:

```
cat /path/to/url.txt|xargs curl -o /path/to/output.txt
```

This will download the page source for all of the URLs (as i can see this happening in command line), but it will only save (in `output.txt`) the page source for the URL at the top of the list.

How would I go about saving page source for each URL, whether in the same text file or if necessary in individual text files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can get multiple URLs in parallel and you do not need to worry about the outputs getting mixed:

```
cat /path/to/url.txt | parallel curl > /path/to/output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

with a simple list of urls on each line, this should do the job and output everything in a single file :

```
while read in; do xargs curl -K "$in" >> /path/to/output.txt; done < /path/to/url.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(cat urls.txt); do curl "$i" >> output.txt; done
```